# Use of implicit parameter in for-loop causes hang

Tags: raku

Consider the following code

```
my $a = "AABBCCBGG";
say join "\n", do for $a.comb.squish {
  $a ~~ s/^ ($_+) //;
}
```

versus

```
my $a = "AABBCCBGG";
say join "\n", do for $a.comb.squish -> $b {
  $a ~~ s/^ ($b+) //;
}
```

The first hangs forever while the last executes as expected. Is this an error or is there some finer detail while using the implicit $_ that I don't understand? Using Rakudo Star 2019.03.01.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code using `$_` contains the moral equivalent of:

```
/''+/
```

which loops forever (because the empty string `''` matches an infinite number of times).

(Well, I've shown just a simple match, and `$_` must be assigned or bound to some value that coerces to a string or the infinite loop won't happen, and your code has to go around its loop twice for it to become a moral equivalent to the above, but those are red herrings.)

> is there some finer detail while using the implicit `$_` that I don't understand?

From [the smartmatch doc](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/~~):

> The smartmatch operator aliases the left-hand side to `$_`

In code:

```
lhs ~~ rhs;
```

is equivalent to:

```
$_ := lhs;
rhs.ACCEPTS(lhs);
```

I suspect you're not taking the first of the two lines above into account.

(Just use the second line on its own if you wish to avoid this topicalization.<sup>1</sup>)

Presuming `$_` is assigned a defined non-empty string:

```
s/$_//;
```

will *always* update `$_` to be an empty string (`''`).

And:

```
$a ~~ s/^ ($_+) //;
```

will alias `$_` to `$a` and then update both `$_` and `$a` to be an empty string.

So the second time around the `for` loop the `~~` again aliases `$_` to `$a`, which now contains an empty string, and then you arrive at the infinite loop condition my answer began with.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> In a comment below Jo asks *why* `~~` *needs* to "topicalize" (alias `$_` to the lhs). The authoritative answer is presumably stored in @Larry's collective brain, which is arguably expressed best by [the P6 design documents](https://web.archive.org/web/20190202080246/https://design.perl6.org/) (in page searches for "smart match" and "smartmatch" seem to be the ticket). But I'll write my own thoughts on this matter.

First, aiui, it doesn't *need* to be this way.

Aiui @Larry could have just decided that constructs that rely on the current topic (which I think means `//`, `s///` and suitable routine calls) do as they do with P5.

Here's some code that runs in both P5 (with suitable pragmas) and P6:

```
my $a = 'a value';
$_ = 'another value';
say $a ~~ s/value/changed string/;
say $a;
say $_;
```

What would you expect the results to be?

In P5:

```
a value
another changed string
```

In P6:

```
｢value｣
a changed string
another value
```

P5 leaves `$a` untouched, modifies `$_`, then compares the modified result with the original `$a` and concludes they don't match (so the `say $a ~~ ...` line says a blank line).

P6 aliases the `$_` to `$a` *for the duration of the smart match*, leaves `$a` permanently modified  per the `s///`, and restores `$_` to its prior value afterwards.

If we stuck with the P5 way we also couldn't write stuff like:

- `foo ~~ / ... /` and have it be true if `foo` matches the regex;
- `my $a = 'AA'; $a ~~ .uc` and have it be true regardless of the value of `$_`  before or after this bit of code;
- `foo ~~ .&bar` match where `bar` is a sub expecting an argument and we want it to get `foo`.

In the meantime, `.ACCEPTS` is also available. So it's not like you *can't* do the same thing as P5. It's just that, by default, constructs that act on the topic work as perhaps folk might expect if they *weren't* exposed to P5 first, and `@Larry` deemed that a good thing overall.

In summary, Jo, I hear that P5 does what you *expect*, but presume that's at least in part because you've *used* P5 and your expectations are based in large part on what it does, and wonder if it remains what you *prefer* after considering the above and giving yourself enough time to absorb it. I'd love to hear a follow up comment from you about how it feels a month from now!

At least, that's my current thoughts on this, er, topic.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough explanation. I understand *why* it happens now, but I have to ask... why do the smartmatch operator need to alias lhs to $_? It doesn't seem self explanatory to me. For once Perl 5 seems to do be more along the lines of my expectations.

Comment: @JoChristianOterhals Good question. I've added my thoughts on the topic in a footnote. I'd especially emphasize how *hygienic* the P6 approach is; `$_` is left untouched once the expression is done when you write `$foo ~~ s/.../.../`. Do P5 *novices* expect `$foo` to be left untouched and `$_` modified instead?

Comment: Well, after 20 years it's difficult to imagine what novices think. But I've always -- probably too simplified -- thought of $_ to be a variable with data fed by the current block; sub {} for {} while {} grep {} etc. The smartmatch operator doesn't visually indicate its blockiness, so to speak. As for novices I'd imagine that two visually different scenarios are more diffcult to grasp than one, but maybe that's just me. But more importantly: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions! It's very helpful.

Comment: @JoChristianOterhals Thx. There are also statement modifiers: `print for 1,2` in P5. So that's a sort of prefix topicalization for the duration of a block or a postfix topicalization for the duration of a statement. P6 retains these and adds built ins that do a third level namely infix operators that topicalize for the duration of their infix operation. Off the top of my head I can think of three: `~~` and [`andthen`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/andthen)/`orelse`.

Answer (score 4):

As usual, Raiph's answer is correct. I only add a small example that proofs what he says.

If you change the example to this:

```
my $a = "AABBCCBGG";
say join "\n", do for $a.comb.squish {
    say "Pre-s/// $_";
    $a ~~ s/^{say "Checking $_"} ($_+) //;
}
```

It will print

```
Pre-s/// A
Checking AABBCCBGG
$a is 
Pre-s/// B
Checking
```

And then hang. Before entering the smartmatch, it holds the loop variable, but as soon as it's in the smarmatch, it changes to whatever is being smartmatched, and it's substituting the whole string by nothing, so since `$a` is the null string in the second iteration, it hangs up.

Conclusion: use the topic variable only if you're very sure it's not being used elsewhere.